# Deserializing nested json objects. When inner object might differ

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

The service I'm dealing returning different objects nested into a generic object. Here are sample mockup results from service

```
{"date":1591430887.591481,"results":[{"identity":"result_type_a","result":{"attr_a":1591427634}}]}
```

```
{"date":1591430887.591481,"results":[{"identity":"result_type_b","result":{"attr_b":1591427634,"attr_bb":3591457634}}]}
```

```
{"date":1591430887.591481,"results":[{"identity":"result_type_c","result":{"attr_c":1591427634,"attr_cc":3591457634,"attr_cc":59634}},{"identity":"result_type_d","result":{"attr_d":"rfrvr","attr_dd":"ytur"}}]}
```

I tried creating a generic object with declaring result attribute as string. And planning that I could deserialize to the returning json to that generic object, check identity attribute and deserilize the string in result attribute to specific object type.

Here is the object structure

```
public class GeneralResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public double Date { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public List<GenericResults> Results { get; set; }


}
public class GenericResults
{
    [JsonProperty("identity")]
    public string Identity { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

To serialize/deserialize I'm using Newtonsoft library and the code is below

```
    public static GeneralResponse SerializeResponse(string response)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeneralResponse>(response);
    }
```

Unfortunately I got following exception while deserializing generic object.

"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'results[0].result', line 1, position 71."

If I declare Result property of GenericResult as object as below

```
public class GenericResults
{
    [JsonProperty("identity")]
    public string Identity { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public object Result { get; set; }
}
```

I can pass first serialization and make the second serialization without getting any exception.

```
        string inner_object = response.Result.ToString();
        switch (type)
        {               
            case ResponseTypes.type_A: return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectTypeA>(inner_object);
            case ResponseTypes.type_B: return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectTypeB>(inner_object);
            case ResponseTypes.type_C: return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectTypeC>(inner_object);
            default: throw new Exception("Unknown Response Type");
        }
```

But returned object does not contain the data. 
I would appreciate any help about modeling this algorithm. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your `Result` should be a polymorphic type hierarchy.  To deserialize such a type hierarchy see [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182) and [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8030538/3744182), of which this looks to be a duplicate.  Agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `string` with JSON.NET serialization it is not actually using the JSON string but tries to parse a JSON string value.

You could use `JObject` instead, which is JSON.NETs wrapper for JSON objects. The `JObject` can then be used to deserialize into a type or by used to access JSON properties directly. Like this:

```cs
switch (type)
{               
    case ResponseTypes.type_A: return response.Result.ToObject<ObjectTypeA>(inner_object);
    case ResponseTypes.type_B: return response.Result.ToObject<ObjectTypeB>(inner_object);
    case ResponseTypes.type_C: return response.Result.ToObject<ObjectTypeC>(inner_object);
    default: throw new Exception("Unknown Response Type");
}
```

Comment: I didn't know this. Tried this but didn't make a difference. Are there any other thing that I should change in code?

Comment: @Emre I have update my answert to include an example on how to convert a `JObject` by using `.ToObject<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for the update but it didn't work. I guess inner_object sholdn't be there?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Dictionary to store the *result*, which looks to be polymorphic. For example,

```
   public partial class GeneralResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public double Date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("results")]
        public ResultElement[] Results { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ResultElement
    {
        [JsonProperty("identity")]
        public string Identity { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public Dictionary<string,object> Result { get; set; }
    }
```

[Working Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SzDJzQ)

Output Sample

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It's a good idea but the object types are not dictionary actually. I simplified objects in order to focus on critical parts.